# mysqli include in array repeated value

Tags: php, mysqli

I want `$teacherIDList` to include the teacherID when it loops with the same courseID for example I want it to be `('RITC01','RITC01')` but at the moment it is only `('RITC01')`.

PHP:

```
function getTeacherID($subjectID) {
    require ('dbconnect.php');
    $teacherIDSQL = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT teacherID FROM TeacherClassRoomCourse WHERE courseID = '$subjectID'");
    $teacherIDList = [];
    while($teacherID = mysqli_fetch_array($teacherIDSQL,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($teacherIDList, $teacherID['teacherID']);
        return $teacherIDList;
    }  
}
getTeacherID('COMP12');
```

dbconnect.php contains `$dbc` which connects to the database.

TeacherClassRoomCourse table:

[image: TeacherClassRoomCourse sql table]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is move the return of the array you are building outside the while loop like this

```
function getTeacherID($subjectID) {
    require ('dbconnect.php');
    $teacherIDSQL = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT teacherID FROM TeacherClassRoomCourse WHERE courseID = '$subjectID'");
    $teacherIDList = [];
    while($teacherID = mysqli_fetch_array($teacherIDSQL,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($teacherIDList, $teacherID['teacherID']);

    }  
    return $teacherIDList;
}
$someting = getTeacherID('COMP12');
```

Answer (score 1):

You `return` inside the `while` loop, so it breaks after the first iteration. Move the `return` outside the loop so it can iterate over all the results, and not just the first.

```
function getTeacherID($subjectID) {
    require ('dbconnect.php');
    $teacherIDSQL = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT teacherID FROM TeacherClassRoomCourse WHERE courseID = '$subjectID'");
    $teacherIDList = [];
    while($teacherID = mysqli_fetch_array($teacherIDSQL,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($teacherIDList, $teacherID['teacherID']);
    }  
    return $teacherIDList; // Return after while is complete
}
```

Notes:

1. You're also vulnerable to SQL injection, and should use parameterized queries with placeholders instead.
2. You're not doing anything with `getTeacherID()` in your code, you'll need to assign it to a variable `$results = getTeacherID('COMP12');`

## References

- http://php.net/return
- http://php.net/mysqli.prepare
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)